# MS Access using Access sql - Null function

Tags: ms-access-2016

Using Null function in access.

I have four different reports. All have order numbers in it. Populating Order number in the report A where Order number matches in report B, C & D in separate columns for each report. So for e.g. Where order numbers from report B matches in report A then populate the order number otherwise nothing (i don't know if this means it is blank or Null where it doesn't have matching order number)Ok so now after populating each of the three columns in report A.
I want to add a query which looks at each column in the report A by using Null function and where it founds order number in any of the columns then it says "Either" if all the columns are "Null/Blank" then say 'None".

I am not a coder. so if you reply then requesting please write me an exact SQL i can use by changing the reports name.

```
SELECT 
    [04_Match to Pending Consolidation].*,
    IIf(IsNull([Matched_Closed_Not_Invoiced_Report],0) + IsNull([Matched_Shipped_Not_Invoiced_report],0)+IsNull([Matched_Pending_Consolidation_Report],0),"NONE","EITHER REPORT") AS Validation 
FROM 
    [04_Match to Pending Consolidation];
```

i want to so "Either" or "None" in the fourth column through this query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be reduced to:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IIf(([Matched_Closed_Not_Invoiced_Report] + [Matched_Shipped_Not_Invoiced_report] + [Matched_Pending_Consolidation_Report]) Is Null, "NONE", "EITHER") AS Validation 
FROM 
    [04_Match to Pending Consolidation];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in which the expression may be written to achieve the same result. The method most similar to your current code might be to use the [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function to return `0` if a given expression is null, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.*,
    IIf
    (
        (
            Nz(t.[Matched_Closed_Not_Invoiced_Report], 0) + 
            Nz(t.[Matched_Shipped_Not_Invoiced_report], 0) + 
            Nz(t.[Matched_Pending_Consolidation_Report], 0)
        ) = 0,
        "NONE",
        "EITHER REPORT"
    ) AS Validation 
FROM 
    [04_Match to Pending Consolidation] t;
```

This of course assumes that each of the fields in question hold a numerical value when not null.

---

Another possible method is to use boolean logic with the [`Is Null`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd#__toc272228352) operator, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.*,
    IIf
    (
        t.[Matched_Closed_Not_Invoiced_Report] Is Null And
        t.[Matched_Shipped_Not_Invoiced_report] Is Null And
        t.[Matched_Pending_Consolidation_Report] Is Null,
        "NONE",
        "EITHER REPORT"
    ) AS Validation 
FROM 
    [04_Match to Pending Consolidation] t;
```

Comment: @MazHak You're most welcome. If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site - many thanks.